# What is the difference between these two params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, parameters

I'm a beginner in rails, I want to know what is the diiference between these two:

```
params["user_id"]
```

and

```
params[:user_id]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In first call, you pass [string](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html) to `[]` method, in secod, you pass [symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html). 
Since `params` returns `HashWithIndifferentAccess` instance, there's no difference in returned object.

More about `HashWithIndifferentAccess` class [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html).